# Open Pop3 C# Ayudaaa

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema que tiene que leer unos correos electrónicos, procesarlos y eliminarlos(mover a la carpeta de eliminados), el problema es que los elimina para siempre no los mueve a la carpeta de eliminados. estoy usando OpenPop3 para todo esto en la documentación de esta herramienta no me muestra nada sobre mover emails

Comment: Pon tu codigo para que se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: si es lo que pienso, con el protocolo POP3 lo que haces es eliminar los correos del servidor, y los pega en la maquina que los esta solicitando, por lo tanto con esa librería lo que haces es un cortar y pegar, creo que a eso te refieres, a lo mejor tu lo quieres hacer todo en el servidor de correo?

Comment: Si mi sistema tiene que leer correos y procesarlos pero no quiero procesar toda la bandeja de entrada todo el tiempo, por eso quiero moverlos a otra carpeta pero no eliminarlos para siempre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con POP3 no vas a poder moverlos de carpeta, para eso deberías utilizar IMAP.
Con la librería [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) podés hacerlo fácil, por ejemplo:

```
var uids = folder.MoveTo (uidMails, destino);
foreach (var uid in uids) {
    Console.WriteLine ("El mensjae con UID {0} en el folder {1} ahora es {2} en {3}",
                       uid, folder.FullName, uidMap[uid], destination.FullName);
}
```

Suerte!

Comment: Gracias cambie de protocolo y funcionó sin problemas